# Is One Function/Object Visually Inside Another Function/Object in Plot / Image

Tags: python, matlab, plot, calculus

I need to use either **Python** or **Matlab**, for this problem.

I have the following plot and equations below, which are also available [on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n9pk5hvcmf).

How can I determine whether **red circle 1** is in **region A** or **region B**?

Current Approach(es):

1. use a lot of if statements to figure out where the circle is relative to every region, but this makes for a confusing program that would require a lot of careful recoding if the shapes of the regions change.
2. generate a set of all points (x,y) that lie in each region and then check whether the points at the boundaries of the circle are are contained in one of those sets. ...but this seems very naive and inefficient.

Note:

The real problem involves more complex shapes created from piecewise functions, but I thought this would be a good starting point.

[image: One Function Inside Another IMAGE?]

Comment: Circles can be transformed into polar coordinates, and sample for different angles to compare the radius, between the circle and the function.

Comment: Are you saying I should get different points on the circle and then check each of those against all the regions? If so, how I can do this without a lot of if statements that would only work for this problem?

Comment: You've tagged both [calculus] and [opencv]. Do you want a calculus solution (as the answer you've got) or an computer vision solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

f1 = lambda theta : 3 / np.cos(2/5 * np.arcsin(np.sin(5*2*theta)))
c1 = lambda theta : np.sqrt(0.1)

inside, outside = False, False
for theta in np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100):
    if c1(theta) <= f1(theta):
        inside = True
    if c1(theta) >= f1(theta):
        outside = True

if inside and outside:
    print('intersect')
elif inside:
    print('inside')
else:
    print('outside')
```

Given a region `f1` and a circle `c1`, both in polar coordinates. Compute their radius for different `theta`s, and compare them.

The polar coordinates of a circle can by obtained by solving

[image]

for `r`